# Can I use TypeScript only for parts of Angular App?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an Angular 1 app I am converting over to Angular 1.5 and want to start transitioning it to TypeScript. However, it shares an `app.js` with the old version and I don't want to overwrite it quite yet with a TypeScript version.

Is there a way for me to leave the app.js module the way it is - and only tsc for the controllers and services?

Because of the nature of the question - I don't really have a code sample. Assume a classic angular.module for the app, and .controller and .factory for the others.

Comment: Have you tried? Typescript compiles to javascript so there shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is valid TypeScript, therefore you could change any `.js` file to `.ts`, compile it, and it would be unchanged. Typescript is a superset of JavaScript that adds features to JavaScript, it isn't its own thing (like CoffeeScript).

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm worried about how it'll work with those modules being injected into the app etc. But I guess I'll just try it and see if it works. Thanks!